# Could I process the data in the SqlBulkCopy class before import to database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

I want to import data from a spreadsheet to a database table. Unfortunately, the data in the spreadsheet is messy and contains '\n' everywhere. I want to remove it before bulkimport.

The bulk copy procedures actually requires 2 steps. i. copy the data from the spreadsheet to a datase. ii. Execute the SqlBulkCopy to copy all data to the database table

If I could not process the data in the SqlBulkCopy class, what is the best way to do it in the DataSet?

```
    //get the data from the spreadsheet to a dataset
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    oledbConn.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [sheetname]"), oledbConn);
    OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    oleda.SelectCommand = cmd;
    oleda.Fill(ds);

    //execute to bulkcopy with the dataset
    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
    {
        bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = "[DestinationTableName]";
        bulkcopy.WriteToServer(ds.Tables[0]);
    }
```

Comment: Since there *is* the DataTable available after the `Fill`, then do whatever manipulation is desired... just iterate the rows and update the data. (That is, what's the question?)

Comment: True. I just wonder if there is any magic I can use in the SQLBulkCopy class. Thanks @pst.

Comment: Nope. It's not [SSIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Integration_Services) ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code I come up with to remove newline character which will be run after Fill

```
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows) 
{
    foreach (DataColumn dc in ds.Tables[0].Columns) 
    {
       if (dc.DataType == typeof(string)) 
       {
          dr[dc] = dr[dc].ToString().Replace("\n", "");
       }
     }
}
```